# Using using .jars in with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a Java  project called "ood_100" to which I am trying to add 2 jars ([Xtream's jars](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html)).

What I did: `right clicked on the project -> build path -> configure build path -> add external jars`, and then I added 2 jars: `xstream-1.4.2.jar` and `kxml2-min-2.3.0.jar`.

Now, as I understand, I can the classes from the jar in my project. For example, `XStream xstream = new XStream();` should work, but I am getting `error: Xtream cannot be resovled to a type.`

What could be the problem? 
Thanks

Comment: "right click on the project" - which IDE?

Comment: Looks like a typo on the import, error message says Xtream not XStream.

Comment: Are you talking about your IDE? Eclipse? What does "I ass 2 jars" mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you imported the class `com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream`?

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is eclipse, use quick-fix to add an import for the class. If it isn't eclipse, please edit this question to tell us what is actually going on.